# Cannot figure out how to get rid of memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm trying to test for memory leaks in my iphone and I'm not having much luck getting rid of this one.  Here is the code that is leaking.

```
- (id)initWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)aMoc delegate:(id)aDelegate runSync:(BOOL)aRunSync {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.moc = aMoc;
        self.settingsManager = [[VacaCalcSettingsManager alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
        self.delegate = aDelegate;
        calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        self.runSync = aRunSync;
    }

    return self;
}
```

It is leaking on the `self.settingsManager = [[VacaCalcSettingsManager alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:self.moc];` line.

The self.settingManager instance variable is released in the dealloc method of the class.

I'm not sure what other information would be pertinent.  Please let me know and I can provide it.

Thanks for any assistance.

-Mark

Here is the header file.

```
@interface VacaCalcCalculation : NSObject {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc;
    VacaCalcSettingsManager *settingsManager;
    id delegate;
    NSCalendar *calendar;
    NSDate *nextBankLimitDate;
    BOOL runSync;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *moc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) VacaCalcSettingsManager *settingsManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSCalendar *calendar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *nextBankLimitDate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL runSync;

- (id)initWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)aMoc delegate:(id)aDelegate;
```

Comment: Not an IPhone developer, so this my be my lack of knowledge about how the systems work, but it looks like Calendar is just set to a new value, and nothing is done with it.  Maybe there is something going on there?

Comment: Show the header file's declarations for the instance variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `settingsManager` property is set to `retain` then you are retaining an object twice with the line: `self.settingsManager = [[VacaCalcSettingsManager alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:self.moc];`

Try adding `autorelease` to the `alloc]init` or creating a class method on VacaCalcSettingsManager that returns an autoreleased object. Otherwise you could redeclare your property with `assign` so that it does not retain the object a second time.

Comment: or just assign directly to settingsManager instead of calling [self setSettingsManager:]